# React-native android debugger connecting to 10.0.2.2 instead of localhost

Tags: android-emulator, react-native, react-native-debugger

While running app with `react-native run-android` its connecting to  10.0.2.2:8081 instead of localhost:8081 and not able to debug.

Does anyone know how to fix so that it will connect to localhost instead?

Answer (score 34):

On MAC I solved it by doing following:

1. Press `Cmd + M` on emulator screen
2. Dev settings > Debug server host & port for device
3. Set `localhost:8081`
4. Rerun the android app: `react-native run-android`

Debugger is connected now!

Hope it will help others :)

Comment: Thnaks, for open **Dev Settins** use `adb shell input keyevent 82` in windows

Comment: @ZanyarJ.Ahmed and on linux also

Answer (score 3):

You can try to change it through *Dev Settings* > *Debug server & host port for device* on menu, that you can access shaking a device or run `adb shell input keyevent 82` command in a terminal

Answer (score 3):

Just run port forwarding

```
adb -s emulator-5554 reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
```

OR your api server to port 5000

```
adb -s emulator-5554 reverse tcp:5000 tcp:5000
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have created a network_security_config.xml file to allow for hardware devices to connect, this can be the source of the issue.  Just add localhost and 10.0.2.2 in that file, and you should be good.

eg. network_security_config.xml file:

```
<network-security-config>
  <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
    <domain includeSubdomains="false">localhost</domain>
    <domain includeSubdomains="false">10.0.2.2</domain>
    <domain includeSubdomains="false">192.168.0.12</domain>
  </domain-config>
  <base-config>
    <trust-anchors>
        <certificates src="system"/>
        <certificates src="user"/>
    </trust-anchors>
  </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a little package for this because it was driving me nuts having to open the screen, especially when using and restarting multiple emulators. Check it out [here](https://github.com/nick-bull/react-native-debug-address) and an example project [here](https://github.com/nick-bull/react-native-debug-address-exemplar):

```
npm i @nick-bull/react-native-debug-address

# DEBUG_HOST=127.0.0.1:8081 npx react-native start --port 8081
# or, equivalently
DEBUG_PORT=8081 npx react-native start --port 8081

npx react-native run-android --port 8081
```